# CoreImage framework does not work?

Tags: objective-c, filter, core-image

i have a problem with the Core Image filters.
The code is pretty simple. I create a new project "single view app";
add CoreImage framework.. (here do i ned to add any header file?)
add an uiiamgeview...and set an image to its.image.
However, when i tried the following code, it did not show any effect.
could you plz give me a hand with the mistake or error?
btw, I'm running the program under simulator 5.0 with Xcode 4.2.1
Thanks in advance.

```
CIImage *backgroundciImage = self.sourceImageView.image.CIImage;
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

//set the filter
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGammaAdjust"];
[filter  setDefaults];
[filter setValue:backgroundciImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[filter  setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f] forKey:@"inputPower"];

//get the output image
CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
self.sourceImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
```

Comment: no one????? what happen?   omg

Answer (score 0):

The below code Works for me., and

```
CIImage *image = [filterTemp valueForKey: @"outputImage"];    
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIFilter* filterBW = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGammaAdjust"];
[filterBW setValue:image forKey:@"inputImage"]; 
[filterBW setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.00f]  forKey: @"inputPower"]; 
CIImage *resultImage = [filterBW valueForKey: @"outputImage"];
self.sourceImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:resultImage fromRect:resultImage.extent]];
```

or in your case You can declare the CIImage *backgroundciImage in respective .h file .,